# Java 8 Stream help when multiple loops

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of students and within that, I have a list of classes with the 3 fields-group, name and category as shown below :

```
{
    
    "students": [
        {
            "classes": [
                {
                    "group": "A",
                    "name": "studentA",
                    "category": "COGAT"
                },
                {
                    "group": "A",
                    "name": "studentB",
                    "category": "COGAT"
                },
                {
                    "field": "A",
                    "name": "studentC",
                    "category": "OTHER"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "classes": [
                {
                   "group": "B",
                    "name": "studentD",
                    "category": "COGAT"
                },
                {
                    "group": "B",
                    "name": "studentE",
                    "category": "COGAT"
                },
                {
                    "group": "B",
                    "name": "studentF",
                    "category": "COGAT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use Stream in Java 8 and loop through the students and then classes and filter the students by group. If it matches Group A- then I want to add all those students names in the new list. Can someone help me with this? As I am not sure how to write nested streams and then match with some boolean value and then again add to the list.

Comment: Can you give us a result example and what is your attempt? Have you tried to use traditional structures like a simple loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> studentNamesInClassA = students.stream()
  .filter(student -> student.getClasses().stream().anyMatch(cls -> "A".equals(cls.getGroup())))
  .map(student -> student.getName())
  .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

The `filter` part filters out only students for which the following `student.getClasses().stream().anyMatch(cls -> "A".equals(cls.getGroup()))` results to `true`. Then, the `map` part "extracts" only the name of those students and the `collect` part - well, collects them to a list.

P.S. I'd extract the condition of the `filter` in a method. E.g.

```
// ...
List<String> studentNamesInClassA = students.stream()
  .filter(student -> studentIsInClassA(student))
  .map(student -> student.getName())
  .collect(Collectors.toList();
// ...

private static boolean studentIsInClassA(Student student) {
    return student.getClasses().stream()
      .anyMatch(cls -> "A".equals(cls.getGroup()));
}
```

Comment: really appreciate your help here. it works with the examples you have shown here . thanks :)

Comment: If I want to run these streams multiple times for different match values - A or B , can I all do in the same stream ? Or for every match it’s suggested to write different flows.

Comment: Instead of collecting to list, you can do `Collectors.groupingBy(student -> student.getName())`. You would also have to drop the filter

Comment: thanks for ur help here. is it also possible to null check these filter values here?

Comment: Is it possible to get the 2 values same time , like fetch "group" and also the "category" values in the same stream and set them to variable or something?

Comment: Yes, using the `Collectors.groupingBy` I mentioned before. If you want to drop nulls, you can use `.filter(x -> x != null)`